# Java angle of line segment

Tags: java, geometry

[image]

In situation like above, I want to check an angle between `b` and `c`.
 
Mathematically it's just

```
asin(a/c)
```

but in Java I have stumbled upon a little problem. That's how I'm trying to achieve the same:

```
Math.asin(Math.toRadians(a/c));
```

I read that `Math.asin()` expects an argument in radians, and that's why I perform a conversion. But it doesn't seem to work as expected. I want to get result in degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arcsine function **returns** radians, it doesn't **accept** them as argument. Convert your return value to degrees.